# Stream flv in android

Tags: android, streaming-flv-video

Hey all, I'm trying to create an app for android that can stream flv files from the web. The `VideoView` does not support this. Other players like `RockPlayerLite` do support flv and play the file fine if it is placed on the sdcard, but i can't find a api on hw to call this as a new intent.

Does anyone know of a flv player that has an API so i can call it from my app with an url that it should load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually very easy:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(PATH_TO_FILE), "video/flv");
startActivity(intent);
```